# How to create a new Account using programmatic configuration in Apache Shiro?

Tags: java, apache, jakarta-ee, ini, shiro

I'm newer in Apache Shiro, and I want to make a simple example using programmatic configuration. When using the file.INI it is simple to create users and grant them roles and  permissons, now,  I want to make the same thing but with using simple java objects. So how can I do that please?

Here is my code:

```
import org.apache.shiro.SecurityUtils; 
import org.apache.shiro.authc.*; 
import org.apache.shiro.config.Ini; 
import org.apache.shiro.config.Ini.Section; 
import org.apache.shiro.config.IniSecurityManagerFactory; 
import org.apache.shiro.mgt.SecurityManager; 
import org.apache.shiro.session.Session; 
import org.apache.shiro.subject.Subject; 
import org.apache.shiro.util.Factory; 
import org.slf4j.Logger; 
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory; 

public class TestShiro { 

    //private static final transient Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestShiro.class); 

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        //Factory<SecurityManager> factory = new IniSecurityManagerFactory("classpath:shiro.ini"); 
    Ini ini = new Ini(); 
    //HERE I SHOULD ADD ACCOUNTS TO MY OBJECT ini
    Factory<SecurityManager> factory = new IniSecurityManagerFactory(ini); 
    Factory<SecurityManager> factory = new IniSecurityManagerFactory(ini); 
        SecurityManager securityManager = factory.getInstance(); 
        SecurityUtils.setSecurityManager(securityManager); 
        Subject currentUser = SecurityUtils.getSubject(); 

        if ( !currentUser.isAuthenticated() ) { 
            UsernamePasswordToken token = new UsernamePasswordToken("lonestarrn", "vespaa"); 

            //this is all you have to do to support 'remember me' (no config - built in!): 
            token.setRememberMe(true); 
            try { 
                currentUser.login( token ); 
            } catch ( UnknownAccountException uae ) { 
            } catch ( IncorrectCredentialsException ice ) { 
            } catch ( LockedAccountException lae ) { 
            } 
             catch ( AuthenticationException ae ) { 
            } 

        } 

        if ( currentUser.hasRole( "schwartz" ) ) { 
            System.out.println("May the Schwartz be with you!" ); 
        } else { 
            System.out.println( "Hello, mere mortal." ); 
        } 

    } 
}
```

I need your help and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Have you already tryed this?

```
Ini ini=new Ini();
Ini.Section section = ini.addSection(IniRealm.USERS_SECTION_NAME);
section.put("guest", "guest, guest");
section.put("lonestarr", "vespa, goodguy");
```

I got it from [here](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.apache.shiro.config.Ini).